# Getting the URL of the calling page Java

Tags: java, spring, controller, request

To put you in the picture, we're using a custom server based on Tomcat 6.0.29. We're developing using Java and Spring.

Let's say I have a link which takes you from http://localhost/display to http://localhost/save. In the controller of http://localhost/save, can I get http://localhost/display from the request parameter somehow?

[`request.getRequestURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) seems to get the url of the current page.

Answer (score 10):

This should give you the referring page (is most cases)

```
request.getHeader("referer");
```

See here for details http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14

And [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) for more details on the request API

Answer (score 2):

You can use "referrer" header to check the page from where the request was made. However it would not work in all cases.

One way could be to set a cookie on http://localhost/display and unset it on http://localhost/save. That way you would know if user visited display prior to save.